# Fxed world-wide IPs for testing country detection?

Tags: http, geolocation, integration-testing, maxmind

I am integrating my application with some country-detection module.
Overall logic is:

1. detect client IP
2. lookup IP in Geo IP DB (for simplicity let's
   assume it is MaxMind DB)
3. identify country code based on IP
4. Some other business logic based off that country code

That works very well, but I am having problems writing automated integration tests.

There is a way to override (force) certain test IPs, but the problem is that all IPs are periodically changing, and time to time I am getting my tests failed because of that.

Any ideas how to stabilize such tests? 
One thought I had is if there was a directory of main ISPs across the world, but could not find it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the GeoIP lookup service in your test environment to return fixed values for certain test IPs. But this only tests #4. To test #1,2,3, you need to use real IP addresses.

If your needs are limited to only a few countries, you can purchase private proxies with fixed IPs and run your tests through a proxied client with a fixed IP.

To automate at scale, you can look at [https://www.geoscreenshot.com](https://www.geoscreenshot.com/), it provides an API for visually testing many locations simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use VPN to test applications. Some providers offer free servers in fixed countries.

If it is a web application, you can use http://www.locabrowser.com to test page view from different servers in multiple countries.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use the CSV file of IPs that MaxMind use for their unit tests (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23616234/354709)